# Nginx regex and wildcard for location

Tags: regex, nginx, wildcard

I am stuck with one issue. I am trying to hit 
http://localhost/api/hello/somename

Now somename could be anything sam or phil,

now my config file of nginx is below.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8081/api/hello/$1;
   }

}
```

Where I am wrong ? Can you pls help me to fix. Actually on 8081 container is running.

Comment: (.*) matches 'hello/somename' here. You're proxying to http://localhost:8081/api/hello/hello/somename.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to make it this complex. You could just it as simple as below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location /api/ {
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8081/api/;
   }

}
```

And that should pass anything starting with `/api` to `http://localhost:8081/api/`, with the request uri after `/api/` appended

Answer (score 2):

`/` should be escaped
`.*` is anything. If you know there should be names and `/` between them say it

```
  ^https?:\/\/\w+\/api(?:\/\w+)*$
```

`http` or `https` then `:` then `//`, then a word, then `/api`, then maybe some `/word`

[test](https://regex101.com/r/Y0MK3e/1)